# How to Host an Image in Mongo DB Database from Input Field So That It Can Be Fetched as Image URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I want a way so that when people upload an Image in the input field along with other informations , the image will be stored to mongoDB database as an image url. So that when I will fetch the data through GET API it will also come along other data as an actual Image URL.

Till now I have done this by pasting image URL to the input field of the form. But this is ofcourse not an efficient process. People will not paste image URL . Rather they will upload the image from their local computer to the form. But I just want to host that image somewhere automatically so that it can be kept as Image URL to the Mongo DB database. How can I do that?

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h1 className="mb-lg-0 mb-5 text-center">
        Please Add New Book To Your Store
      </h1>
      <Form.Group
        className="mb-3 mt-5"
        controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1"
      >
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Your Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          disabled={authUser?.displayName ? true : false}
          value={authUser?.displayName}
          type="text"
          placeholder="First Name"
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="email"
          placeholder="name@example.com"
          value={authUser?.email}
          required
          disabled={authUser?.email ? true : false}
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Book Cover Image</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Image URL of the Book"
          required
          name="image"
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Book Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name Of Your Book"
          required
          name="bookName"
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Name of Author</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          name="author"
          placeholder="Book Author Name"
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Description</Form.Label>

        <Form.Control
          as="textarea"
          rows="3"
          placeholder="Description Of Your Book"
          required
          name="description"
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Price</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="number"
          name="price"
          placeholder="Number of Stock"
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
        <Form.Label className="checkout-labels">Number Of Stock</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="number"
          name="quantity"
          placeholder="Number of Stock"
          required
        />
      </Form.Group>

      <Button
        className="px-5 d-block mx-auto checkout-labels"
        variant="primary"
        type="submit"
      >
        Add This Item To The Store
      </Button>
    </Form>
```

Comment: Hey there! Based on what I understand, you want to take the image blob, upload it to some storage online, then use that URL and store it?

Comment: Yes exactly. But it will happen automatically when the user uploads the image in input field of the form and submit it. How can I do that?

Comment: Ah okay, are you working with a specific cloud provider? Can you provide some more details about your application stack?

Comment: I am using Mongo Db only and Firebase for authentication. For hosting the image I use ImageBB. but I have to upload the image there manually and have to create the image URL. Is there any way that the image will be hosted some where automatically when the user uploads the image and the URL of the image will be posted to the Mongo DB database?